# Need advice, Saving messages from JMS Queue to Hadoop Hbase a good solution?

Tags: java, hadoop, architecture, hbase, message-queue

I'm new to the Hadoop world and I've been tasked to research solutions to ingest data from our current JMS Queues into our Hadoop cluster.

So far on my quest to becoming a data ingestion expert... I've scoured the web going through books and tutorials for a couple of weeks now. I've managed to write a simple Java Service which listens to one of our Queues and simply write the incoming messages to an HBase HTable.

After completing this proof of concept I have a couple of questions I would like ask the community/Hadoop/Hbase/data ingestion experts. Before I ask let me describe a little bit of my scenario/scope.

- We receive approximately 30,000 messages per day from our JMS Queue
- These messages are JSON objects which can range anywhere from 1 MB to 20 MB each
- Needs to be near real time
- We would like to continuously save these messages into Hadoop for future analytics and historical reference for years to come
- We don't need to parse the incoming messages, just store them. (Current line of thinking is to write another Service which will parse these messages and save them into proper schema later. Reason = No bottlenecking during message ingestion)

With my "proof of concept" Java Service, it works, but I don't know if this solution is the best for my case scenario especially in a Production environment.

1. Is this a good approach/solution for my case scenario?
2. If not, what other technologies would be a good fit for what I'm trying to do?
3. Is using HBase for this overkill?
4. Saving up to 20 MB in a single cell a good idea? Especially if we plan to continuously append messages to this table with no purging?

Appreciate any input, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a good approach/solution for my case scenario?
>   If not, what other technologies would be a good fit for what I'm trying to do?

Flume can be another option. It provides jms source and HBase/Hive sinks.

> Is using HBase for this overkill?

May not be, if the number of messages run into a large number over a period of time based on your daily input.
What is the purpose of storing messages in HBase if you plan to parse it out again into another store.
Depending on your needs, the another service (example, mapreduce) can consume jms messages, process it and output to what ever final destination you are thinking of instead of HBase. Unless you have a need to store original messages for a long term.

Comment: Thanks @techuser for you input.

Comment: Purpose/Big picture, we need to capture/retain these original messages in their raw form into Hadoop so that we can "replay" selected messages or desired date ranges of messages back into our system or a model in the future.  HTable wise, let’s assume worst case scenario that all messages are 20 MB each. So 20 MB x 30,000 x 356 = 213,600,000 MB (213.6 Terabytes). In which each year would at a minimum double itself. Would HTable be able to handle a table of this size especially with row cells that are 20 MB (MOB enabled)?

Comment: The cluster can grow horizontally. You will need to add more nodes to the hadoop cluster.